# protractor integration with IDE

Tags: angularjs, testing, protractor, webstorm, angularjs-e2e

I have configured webstorm for using protractor, but when I launch my test suit, it does not recognize this param from my config file:

```
// conf.js
exports.config = {
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    specs: ['spec.js'],
    capabilities: {
        browserName: 'firefox'
    }
};
```

In console it says serving "conf.js" at http:// 127.0.0.1:8080. What could be the reason for that? Why it does not use address for my selenium?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is the configuration I have. But it does not use correct URL

Comment: Could you show (screenshot would be good) what run configuration do you have for protractor? Also, what exactly does it says on the console and what happens next? Thanks.

Comment: Here are some screenshots for setup I have.

Comment: I am about solving it, looks like I need to slightly modify cli.js, in order to put here the proper path to the local network interface

Comment: I modified default addresses in cli.js, I do not think that it is proper way, but it still does not work (see last screenshot).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JavaScript file parameter in the webstrom / intellij windown has to point to Protractor's cli.js file under node_modules/protractor

Comment: Yes. Works fine for me when using ~\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\bin\protractor as a javascript file

Comment: thank you, this worked well for me, I used wrong cli.js initially